# Is it possible to publish/unpublish content by language?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I have enabled the the "multilingual with translation" option for the content type.

I have created the node and translate it in 2nd language. In 2nd language I want to unpublish the content but when I unpublished it, it also unpublished the content in the 1st language.

Is it possible to publish/unpublish content by language?

Comment: Duplicate question : https://www.drupal.org/node/2343359

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

In your Content type settings
Synchronize Translations --> Status should be unchecked.